# SQL Query with nested queries, group by, and count

Tags: mysql, sql

> Table: date, user, order_type.

order_type is an enumeration of 4 values: music, books, movies, art.

I need a query that returns the total orders count and count of each order type grouped by user:

```
user, total, music, movies, books, art
--------------------------------------
Adam, 10, 5, 2, 3, 0
Smith, 33, 10, 3, 15,2
mary, 12,6,1,3,2
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT   user,
         COUNT(*)                 AS total,
         SUM(order_type='music')  AS music,
         SUM(order_type='movies') AS movies,
         SUM(order_type='books')  AS books,
         SUM(order_type='art')    AS art
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY user
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select user, count(*) as total, 
    sum(case when order_type = 'music' then 1 else 0) end as music,
    sum(case when order_type = 'movies' then 1 else 0) end as movies,
    sum(case when order_type = 'books' then 1 else 0) end as books,
    sum(case when order_type = 'art' then 1 else 0) end as art
from t
group by user
```